# Angular 4 - formcontrol.setValue() inside OnChanges()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, ngonchanges

Using Angular 4. I have a `paging.component` that gets the **page** number and **pageSize** from it's parent component (after it gets data).

The `paging.component` will look for changes to the `@Input`'s using the `OnChanges` life-cycle hook.

The `paging.component` also has a `<select>` input where you can change the **pageSize**.

During the `OnInit` phase, the `<select>` gets set to the **pageSize** passed in from the parent component.

If you change the **pageSize** with the `<select>`, it all works ok, but I sometimes also want to change the **pageSize** from the parent component to a different value (like the original value).

When I change the **pageSize** from the parent component, however, it does not change the `<select>` input. (Even though everything else seems to work correctly).

I tried adding the following code to the `ngOnChanges` method:

```ts
if (this.pageSizeFG) {
    this.pageSizeCtrl.setValue(this.pagesize);
}
```

However, this gives errors:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

The paging also seems to keep reseting itself to page 1 if I try to go to a different page.

I've looked into some of the other life-cycle hooks, `ChangeDetectorRef`, and `ngZone`, but those seem to make the problem worse.

I have created a [plnkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bBYlW3L9VU0trQ5se0AJ) that demonstrates the error.

If you go to the `paging.component.ts` and comment out the line with `this.pageSizeCtrl.setValue(this.pagesize);`, then everything works fine *EXCEPT* the `<select>` does not update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is being caused by your `ngModelChange` event on your select element + your ngOnchanges lifecycle method.

```
<select (ngModelChange)="setPageSize($event)">...</select>
```

What is happening is

> 1. you pass in a new input to paging.component
> 2. ngOnChanges fires
> 3. within ngOnChanges, this.pageSizeCtrl.setValue(this.pagesize) fires
> 4. This causes the ngModelChange event to fire (setPageSize)
> 5. setPageSize emits to the parent component
> 6. parent changes input which causes ngOnChanges to fire again.

So this all leads to the Expression has changed error.

To fix this, I would use the change event instead of ngModelChange

```
<select (change)="setPageSize()">...</select>
```

This way `setValue()` does not cause the `setPageSize()` event to fire. You will also need to update how `setPageSize()` emits the `pageSize` property.

```
setPageSize() {
    // get pageSizeCtrl value programatically
    let pageSize = +this.pageSizeCtrl.value;
    this.pagechange.emit({ page: 1, pageSize: pageSize });
}
```

Here is a working  plnkr with the fixes (http://plnkr.co/edit/zJEIYJzG5OGRXIfA77Qz?p=preview)